# Automatically add a plus sign with a maximum value after it has been reached

Tags: swift, foundation, nsnumberformatter

Is it possible a `NumberFormatter` (or any other build in class/struct) will return a localized plus sign with a certain maximum value, after it has been reached? I tried this:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.maximum = 9

print(numberFormatter.string(from: 10))
```

But it just returns `"10"`, I expect/hoped for `"9+"` (because my localization is set to english, thus + is here the plus sign and is appended after the 9 since we read from left to right). Is it possible to use an existing class/struct (I thought `NumberFormatter` could do this job) that can handle the localization of a plus sign build in? In other language, the plus sign is different and maybe even in front of the number.

**I don't want to add the plus sign manually.**

I think the `NumberFormatter` should be able to localize the plus sign: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1416423-plussign

Comment: Is there any indication that setting a `maximum` actually does anything? In theory, this is "The highest number allowed as input by the receiver," so I would imagine that something like an exception is thrown if an input exceeds the maximum.

Comment: @Daniel I was suprised also...

Comment: How could the `+` sign be localized?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I don't think everyone around the world is using '+' as suffix to '9' to indicate there are more items than 9.

Comment: I understand maximum is used with numberFormatter.number.

Comment: I understood that, that's why I commented the proposed solution as probably not suited. It was just to show that maximum is effectively used, but not doing what you are looking for.

Comment: @J.Doe can you actually support with examples that this isn't the case in every language? This isn't really an official way to display anything unlike currencies for instance, so I don't think a localisation exists for such thing and I'm pretty sure `NumberFormatter` cannot handle this automatically either

Comment: @DávidPásztor There are a few differences as stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs. It is pretty hard to find out what other languages use, since I do not know the right keywords to search for on google (because you get all kind of other search results when searching for e.g. localized plus sign). Besides the localized plus sign (let's say it always is +), the position may vary (I don't know if arabic will have the plus sign before the number).

Comment: The problem here is that `NumberFormatter` `plusSign`, `positivePrefix`, or `positiveSuffix` have nothing to do with the way you wish to localize your output. In other words, `NumberFormatter` does not support what you wish to do here. I don't think there's anything found in any locale data that indicates how to format a number showing that the result is really "bigger".

Comment: @rmaddy Ok well that sounds like a valid answer to me. Guess I need to come up with an alternative or just let it translated...

Comment: Yeah, I think you’re going to just have to add it to your own localization `.strings` or `.stringsdict` file. As an aside, I wonder if the `limit` should change based upon locale, too? E.g. in English the threshold might be “9+” because we want to avoid tripping into multiple digits, but in in other languages (e.g. Japanese and Chinese), “10” is also a single character, so do they tend to cut off at 9 (九) or 10 (十)? Lol. And on top of that, the character for “ten” coincidentally bears a resemblance to the English “plus”/“more” character, `+`, which is an argument for localizing that character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that would place the plus sign either on the right or the left of the number based on the direction of the language of the current locale :

```
func format(number: Double, limit: Double) -> String {

    if let languageCode = Locale.current.languageCode, number > limit {
        let direction = Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: languageCode)
        if direction == .leftToRight {
            return "\(limit)" + NumberFormatter().plusSign
        } else {
            return NumberFormatter().plusSign + "\(limit)"
        }
    } else {
        return "\(number)"
    }
}

format(number: 10, limit: 9)  //"9.0+"
```

Comment: In the question it literally states: I don't want to add the plus sign manually.

Comment: The use of `plusSign` here isn't necessarily correct for all locales. That symbol is used to show a positive number, not a symbol to indicate the actual result is bigger than the value shown.

Answer (score -1):

This works, even though may not be what you are looking for.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.maximum = 9

func formatMax(_ s: Int) -> String {
        if numberFormatter.number(from: String(s)) == nil {
            return "\(numberFormatter.maximum!)" + "+"
        } else {
            return String(s)
        }
}

print(formatMax(11))
```

Comment: I dont want to add the plus sign manually, it is stated in my question! This isn't localizing, this is just guessing everyone that uses your app has a language that indicates '+' is used for the plus sign and that it comes after the number. This isn't the case in every language.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the job of NumberFormatter, but here is a simple function to do this for you:

```
func ffs(_ number:NSNumber) -> String{
    let max = 9
    if (Int(truncating: number) > max){
        return "\(max)+"} else {
        return "\(number)"
    }
}
```

And then print(ffs(10))